# Time difference with hours, minutes and seconds in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to find time difference between two columns with hours, minutes and seconds.

These are two datetime columns in my table:

```
STOP_TIME                      Start_Time
------------------------------------------------------
2016-05-10 03:31:00.000        2016-05-10 02:25:34.000
```

I calculated second difference for stoptime and starttime. 3926 is the second difference.

I need to convert this to time format `hh:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for you -

```
DECLARE @STOP_TIME DATETIME = '2016-05-10 03:31:00.000',
        @Start_Time DATETIME = '2016-05-10 02:25:34.000'
SELECT 
     RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @Start_Time, @STOP_TIME) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @Start_Time, @STOP_TIME) % 3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @Start_Time, @STOP_TIME) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Comment: Generally this works for under 100 hours, for longer times increase the first part.  For example up to just over 13 months use `RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @Start_Time, @STOP_TIME) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(4)),4) + ':'`

Answer (score 9):

Sql server supports adding and subtracting on Datetime data type, so you can simply do something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime = '2016-05-10 02:25:34.000',
        @EndTime datetime = '2016-05-10 03:31:00.000'

SELECT CAST(@EndTime - @StartTime as Time) As TimeDifference
```

Result: `01:05:26`

**Note:** As TT rightfully wrote in his comment, casting to time will only work if the difference between `@EndTime` and `@StartTime` is less then 24 hours. 
If you need to compare times that are further apart, you need to use one of the other solutions suggested.

Comment: Works for a difference of strictly less than 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, Just now I checked it works for only hours difference less than 24.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any cases:

```
DECLARE @STOP_TIME DATETIME = '2016-05-10 05:27:35.000',
    @Start_Time DATETIME = '2016-05-10 02:25:34.000' 
SELECT CONCAT(format(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start_Time, @STOP_TIME)/3600,'00'),':'
          ,format(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start_Time, @STOP_TIME)%3600/60,'00'),':'
          ,format(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start_Time, @STOP_TIME)%3600%60,'00')
         ) AS 'hrs:mins:secnds'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?